# Change Angular mat expansion panel font

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I change the font of the panel header, title, and content for mat-expansion?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of i.e above Angular Material (7), then this should be  the trick:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-title {
  color: blue
}
```